# Anonymous object in LinQ with join/relations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm pretty new with MVC and the Entity Framework.
I have created a model based on a entity. The new model is being used by the view.
With a query I fill the model:

```
public IEnumerable<TimeTableInsertModel> getTimeTableDetails(int? id)
{
    using (var db = new EFDbContext())
    {
        return (from s in db.TimeTables

                where s.TimeTableId == id
                select new
                {
                    TimeTableId = s.TimeTableId,
                    MovieId = s.MovieId,
                    RoomId = s.RoomId,
                    SeatsAvaible = s.SeatsAvaible,
                    StartTime = s.StartTime,
                    EndTime = s.EndTime,
                    Movie = s.Movie,
                    Reservations = s.Reservations,
                    Room = s.Room,

                    TicketQuantity = 0,
                }).ToList().Select(x => new TimeTableInsertModel
                {
                    TimeTableId = x.TimeTableId,
                    MovieId = x.MovieId,
                    RoomId = x.RoomId,
                    SeatsAvaible = x.SeatsAvaible,
                    StartTime = x.StartTime,
                    EndTime = x.EndTime,
                    Movie = x.Movie,
                    Reservations = x.Reservations,
                    Room = x.Room,
                });
    }
}
```

That works fine. But:
The table 'Movie' has 2 relations with 'Genre'  and 'Language'. Those 2 tables are not filled in the model. And I don't know how to do that.
I have try to do it on this way:

```
Language = s.Movie.Language,
Reservations = s.Reservations,

Genre = x.Movie.Genre,
Language = x.Movie.Language,
```

But Visual Studio says the model does not contain a definition for 'Genre' and 'Language'.

Can anybody help? The original model 'TimeTableModel' has the following content:

```
public partial class TimeTable
{
    public TimeTable()
    {
        Reservations = new HashSet<Reservation>();
    }

    public int TimeTableId { get; set; }
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public int SeatsAvaible { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    public virtual Room Room { get; set; }
}
```

And the TimeTableInsertModel (witch is used by the view):

```
public class TimeTableInsertModel
{
    [Key]
    public int TimeTableId { get; set; }
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public int SeatsAvaible { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
    public virtual Room Room { get; set; }
    public int TicketQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "But Visual Studio says the model does not contain a definition for 'Genre' and 'Language'." Yes, the model does not have such properties. Why does the error surprise you and what do you not understand about it?

Comment: The original model doesn't have the definitions too, but when I use that model they will filled correctly.

Comment: That is not true. You must be confusing classes. Do you understand why the compiler emits this error?

Comment: No, I'm totally lost it :(

Comment: You can't assign to a property that does not exist. For that reason `new TimeTableInsertModel { Genre = ... }` is invalid. Create the property.

Answer (score 0):

Your children are virtual so you need to tell EF to load them. There are several techniques like this:

```
from s in db.TimeTables.Include("Movie.Genre").Include("Movie.Language")
```

That will cause both the movie and it's genre and language children to load.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Hmm, that isn't working. The Genre and Language objects keeps empty.     Message = "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."